# Hungarian ű (double acute accent) not displaying

Tags: accents, hungarian

I am trying to TeX a Hungarian document including **ű** characters. As you can see I am using a UTF-8 encoding with `lmodern`, but the double accented u does not show up:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}    
ű
\end{document}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: \"{u} is a different one (ü). The desired one would be \H{u}. But for me the document works, `ű = \H{u}` gives ű=ű. So what does the log file say?

Comment: This code also works for me.  Is you distribution up to date? Which versions of the packages are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding fontspec looks to be enough, but if it still doesn't work, then you can try adding the missing characters manually as well.

(Note that on MacTeX I had to use `hungarian` instead of `magyar` in the babel settings, as only the former is supported)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec, newunicodechar}
\usepackage[hungarian]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\newunicodechar{ű}{\H{u}}
\newunicodechar{ő}{\H{o}}

\begin{document}
árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép

ÁRVÍZTŰRŐ TÜKÖRFÚRÓGÉP
\end{document}
```

There are still some LaTeX warnings displayed though:

```
LaTeX Warning: Please use \usepackage{t1enc} with
               \usepackage[hungarian]{babel}, to get accented chars hyphenated.

LaTeX Warning: Please use \usepackage[latin2]{inputenc} with
               \usepackage[hungarian]{babel}.
```

But the output is okay:

[image: LuaLaTeX output]

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the logs again I noticed a warning:

```
Package inputenc Warning: inputenc package ignored with utf8 based engines.
```

I am using `lualatex` which always uses **UTF8** so the inputenc is obsolet. The solution is as David mentioned in the comments:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
ű
\end{document}
```

Otherwise you could also change the compiler from `lualtex` to `pdflatex` and use the input given in the question.

Comment: that isn't really an answer. As the warning says the package is ignored in luatex so you should get the same output even if you omit the inputenc package.

Comment: you should almost always never use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` with luatex.

Comment: yes, but the encoding is needed to encode the double accented u. I only had to use lualatex to produce some Feynman diagrams. Switching back to pdflatex solved the problem for me.

Comment: no that is a misunderstanding you do not need inputenc because luatex input  is _always_ UTF8 and you should not use T1 encoding but a natural Uniocde encoded font (the default is in fact latin modern even without the lmodern package) so just using `\usepackage{fontspec}` and not fontenc or inputenc should be fine

Comment: Lualatex uses utf8 as input encoding. So it doesn't need `inputenc` and `inputenc` apparently disables itself under `lualatex`. But then `babel` complains about `inputenc` not used with `magyar`. But even without `babel` and `inputenc`, `lualatex` doesn't know ű and that looks like a bug. For the time being you could use `\H{u}`.

Comment: @PietvanOostrum Babel complains but it compiles and displays the ű